# How to Configure Google Translate API v2 on localhost

Tags: api, google-api, cgi, localhost, google-translate

I am trying to translate text on my basic webpage that I created on localhost However, I always keep receiving the **Access Not Configured. Please enable the Google API** error. I have already enabled the **Translate API** in my Google Developer account, I created both a server and browser API key (any suggestions on what I should add in my referers would be great thanks, my screen dump link underneath may help you with the option).

I was wondering if there is any alternative way I can get this API v2 to work on my localhost machine? Please see screen dump link for error.

Here on the website, I am trying to translate the **UK** word on google.com, with the Translate API V2 enabled and the browser key running in the background of the application I am using for this process, the **UK** word should translate to a language of my choice, however, as shown below, an error pops up.

[Here is the link that shows screen dump](http://efe-ogunkeye.com/u.jpg)

Any one that can help me with this issue, or if you have any further questions please let let me know? Your assistance is much appreciated.

Thanks